# Having some issue reading the child in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

!https://photos.app.goo.gl/8axsEgMJQAsBFnJF9

So I was trying to compare my string with database I wanted to check if the given string by user exists in the database or not. But as I wrote the code,the output is always no. I tried both ValueEventListener and ChildEventListener.

So how can I get the required result.

```
parentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

parentRef.child("Companies").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if ((dataSnapshot.child("jaq").exists())) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if ((dataSnapshot.child("jaq")).exists()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In valueEventListener try the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Companies");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             if(childSnapshot.child("jaq").exists()){
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
       }
  }
      @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      }
  });
```

Here you loop inside the dataSnapshot and then check if child `jaq` exists in the database.